# How to install apache and postgresql server on ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, postgresql, ubuntu

I am working on a wiki project, which is making a portable wiki server via USB. Any idea how to install apache and postgresl server on a single USB? Thanks

Comment: You might have better luck on http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 postgresql-server
```

You might have to specify a postgres version, so do `apt-cache search postgresql` and find the right package for your version.